# Readline menu-complete on OS X

Tags: osx, readline

I'm trying to test out using the `menu-complete` on OS X 10.8, and it's just not working. I have it in my .inputrc as such:

```
"\M-s": menu-complete
```

I then tried to do <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-r</kbd> to reload the `.inputrc` and it's not working. I've quit and re-opened Terminal as well, and it's not working. Is it not supported in OS X? Or am I doing it wrong?

---

**Edit**:

It seems to work in `xterm` (from XQuartz), but not in Terminal